# Index Error using a del in a loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, del

```
search = ['item1', 'item1', 'item1', 'item1', 'item2']
for i in range(len(itemlocs) - 1):
    
    print("List: ", search)
    print("Index: ", itemlocs[i])
    val = int(itemlocs[i])
    print(val)
    del search[val]
```

itemlocs would be ['2', '1', '2', '0']

The error I get is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me and `search = ['item1', 'item1']` at the end

Comment: Tried it with an online interpreter, works: https://onlinegdb.com/SJTv071Ed